# git reflog shows me commits unrelated to my branch. How do I get the commits related to the branch I have checked out?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed and merged some work into another branch when I wasn't meant to. To fix this I need to go back to an earlier commit.

However, when I run `git reflog` I get a list of commits relating to another branch I am working on. None of them are related to the branch I am currently working on and have checked out now.

Would anyone know why this is and how I could find the commits relating to my branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have your branch, use :  `git reflog [yourbanch]`

If you look for the history of `otherbranch` : `git reflog [otherbranch]`

---

`git reflog`, which is a shortcut for `git reflog HEAD`, give you a detailed history of all checked out commits ; this is useful in general (it makes for a great undo stack), but is indeed more noisy.

Answer (score 1):

The format you're using when you do a simple `git reflog` is

```
git reflog [show] [log-options] [<ref>]
```

so you're in fact omitting two arguments, which will be assumed and fall back to their defaults :

```
git reflog show HEAD
```

which ouputs a history of `HEAD` itself, so a list of actions on (provided you *do* have a multiple branches workflow) a mix of different branches.

But you could have specified a branch (EVEN IF the branch happens to already be checked out, since `HEAD` won't be resolved to the current branch here) :

```
git reflog some-feature
```

(here, the `show` action is also implied but the branch is explicit)

---

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog#_description) :

> The "show" subcommand (which is also the default, in the absence of any subcommands) shows the log of the reference provided in the command-line (or HEAD, by default).